# Error with import in .proto file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, protocol-buffers

I have a `MyResponse.proto` file which imports two `.proto` files `Alternative.proto` and `Index.proto`.

`MyResponse.proto` file:

```
import "Alternative.proto";
import "Index.proto";
message MyResponse {
  repeated AlternativeV1 alternativeV1 = 1;
  required IndexV1 indexV1 = 2;
}
```

`Alternative.proto` file:

```
import "Reference.proto";
message AlternativeV1 {
  required string name = 1;
  required string id = 2;
}
```

`Index.proto` file:

```
message IndexV1 {
  required string name = 1;
}
```

I'm getting the error  `"AlternativeV1" is not defined` while compiling the `proto` file using maven. I'm using Intellij as IDE. The types `AlternativeV1` and `IndexV1` are shown as 'unresolved reference' in IDE. Can anyone help me in fixing this issue ?

Comment: Please show us also the files `Alternative.proto` and `Index.proto`.

Comment: I have added the files. Please see the edit

Comment: Does it work if you comment out `Reference.proto` in `Alternative.proto` (as it's not used). Are all `*.proto` files in the same directory?

Comment: @SubOptimal yes I tried commenting out `Reference.proto`. But it didn't work. All the `.proto` files are in same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find below a small working example. So you can compare it with your project settings.

Assume following file and directory structure.

```
pom.xml
src/main/proto/Alternative.proto
src/main/proto/Index.proto
src/main/proto/MyResponse.proto
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sub.optimal</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProtoExample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<!--        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>-->
    </properties>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>protoc-plugin</id>
            <url>https://dl.bintray.com/sergei-ivanov/maven/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-protoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocExecutable>protoc</protocExecutable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Alternative.proto**

```
package sub.optimal;
message AlternativeV1 {
    required string name = 1;
    required string id = 2;
}
```

**Index.proto**

```
package sub.optimal;
message IndexV1 {
    required string name = 1;
}
```

**MyResponse.proto**

```
package sub.optimal;
option java_outer_classname = "MyResponseProtos";
import "Alternative.proto";
import "Index.proto";
message MyResponse {
    repeated AlternativeV1 alternativeV1 = 1;
    required IndexV1 indexV1 = 2;
}
```

The following has been added to the `*.proto` files

- package - to generate valid Java source
- option java_outer_classname - otherwise the `protoc` compiler would generate a default class `MyResponseOuterClass.java`

Running `mvn compile` will generate the classes below `target/classes/sub/optimal/`.

Comment: If the generated java file is in different package, then how can I import it ?

Comment: Then you need to specify the package name. Assume `IndexV1` is declared as `package sub.optimal.foo`, then you have to amend `MyResponse.proto` as `required foo.IndexV1 indexV1 ...`. See the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto