# Proto Java: Import Proto was not found or had errors

Tags: maven, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

Please help me I am really stuck.
I am working for [protocol buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) with maven plugin. I have added two files respectivcley hello.proto and hello2.proto.
While Build the project, I am getting error such as hello2.proto: Import "h/hello.proto" was not found or had errors.

hello.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

//option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.poc_cipertrace.hello";
option java_outer_classname = "HelloWorldRequest";

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}
```

hello.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "com.poc.poc_cipertrace.hello";
option java_outer_classname = "HelloWorldResponse";

import "h/hello.proto";

message HelloResponse {
  HelloRequest h=1;

}
```

POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>poc_cipertrace</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>poc_cipertrace</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
                <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeMavenTypes>direct</includeMavenTypes>
                            <inputDirectories>
                                <include>src/main/resources/proto</include>
                            </inputDirectories>
                            <outputTargets>
                                <outputTarget>
                                    <type>java</type>
                                    <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                                </outputTarget>
                                <outputTarget>
                                    <type>grpc-java</type>
                                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.15.0</pluginArtifact>
                                    <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                                </outputTarget>
                            </outputTargets>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Project Structure

[image]

The expected output is that Java File should generate according to the package. I have tried through various website but I am unable to get the expected output

[Retrieving external .proto files for protoc with protobuf-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48812110/retrieving-external-proto-files-for-protoc-with-protobuf-maven-plugin)

[Error with import in .proto file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34506534/error-with-import-in-proto-file)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Java so can't help with your `POM.xml` but, you proto definitions are incorrect and seemingly unnecessary complex.

TL;DR: assuming you want `h` and `h2` to define packages, you must reference them as such within the `proto` files by adding `package` references that match the path from proto root folder name. In your case, assuming `${PWD}/proto` is the proto path, then e.g. `h/hello.proto` represents the package `h`:

`h/hello.proto`

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package h;

//option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.poc.poc_cipertrace.hello";
option java_outer_classname = "HelloWorldRequest";

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}
```

`h2/hello.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package h2;

option java_package = "com.poc.poc_cipertrace.hello";
option java_outer_classname = "HelloWorldResponse";

import "h/hello.proto";

message HelloResponse {
  h.HelloRequest h=1;
}
```

Then (not using `mvn` but `protoc` directly):

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD}/proto \
--java_out=${PWD} \
${PWD}/proto/h/hello.proto \
${PWD}/proto/h2/hello.proto
```

Yields:

```bash
com
└── poc
    └── poc_cipertrace
        └── hello
            ├── HelloWorldRequest.java
            └── HelloWorldResponse.java
```

Thoughts:

- You had different `java_package` values but I assume you want them in the same Java namespace i.e. `com.pod.pod_cipertrace.hello`
- You will cause yourself unecessary (!?) pain by splitting `HelloRequest` and `HelloResponse` across different `package`'s and using the same filename (`hello.proto`). These could (should!) be merged into a single `proto` in a single `package`.